# Adding anchors to h2 in text using python and regexp

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to add anchors to all h2's in my html, using python. This code will add those anchors, but I need to fill the name of the anchors too.

Any idea if the name can be the number of the match in the loop or a slugified version of the text between the h2 tags?

Here's the code so far:

```
regex = '(?P<name><h2>.*?</h2>)'
text = re.sub(regex, "<a name=''/>"+r"\g<name>", text)
```

Comment: NB: Using `a` elements as anchors are a bit old fashioned. It's more up-to-date and easier to simply set an `id` on the element. Example: `<h2 id="my_anchor">My Headline</h2>` instead of `<h2><a name="my_anchor">My Headline</a></h2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the second argument to [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) can be a function to do pretty much anything you'd like.  Here's an example that will slugify the text inside the `<h2>` element:

```
regex = '(?P<name><h2>(.*?)</h2>)' # Note the extra group inside the <h2>

def slugify(s):
    return s.replace(' ', '-') # bare-bones slugify

def anchorize(matchobj):
    return '<a name="%s"/>%s' % (slugify(matchob.group(2)), matchobj.group(1))

text = re.sub(regex, anchorize, text)
```

(That `slugify` function could obviously use some work.)

You could also implement a counter with a version of `anchorize` that used a global counter or, better yet, a class that kept track of its own counter and implemented the special `__call__` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but is placing the author as the name attribute sufficient?
Maybe you could use (as long as the author name doesn't contain invalid chars for an attribute):

```
regex = '(?P<name><h2>(.*?)</h2>)'
print re.sub(regex, "<a name='\g<2>'/>"+r"\g<name>", text)
```

If you need a more advanced substitution method, parsing the author name or looking up some sort of related id, you could define a replacement function (see [re substitute doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)):

```
def name_substitution(matchobj):
    name = matchobj.group(2)
    # do some processing on name here ...
    name = name.replace(' ', '_')
    return "<a name='%s'>%s</a>" % (name, matchobj.group(0))

print re.sub(regex, substitution, text)
```